# Как реализовать такое меню?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, menu

[image: Меню]

Привет. Появилась задача реализовать такое меню. Идеи есть, но на практике, все идеи отпадают. Гугл нечего нормального не выдает. При клике на пункт меню, остальные пункты должны скрываться. Решение в идеале должно быть резиновым. Подскажите, кто знает:)

Comment: Покажите, что вы уже попробовали сделать. Добавьте к вопросу код.

Comment: использовать SVG, это просто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приблизительно так

```css
.menu{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu > li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    height: 100px;
}
.menu > li .item-wrap {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;    
}
.menu > li .item-wrap a{
   color: #fff; 
    display: block;    
    height: 100%;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
.menu > li .item-wrap a.item-top {    
    background-color: #f00;
    transform-origin: top right;    
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.menu > li .item-wrap a.item-bottom {    
    background-color: #c00;
    transform-origin: bottom left;    
}
.menu > li .item-wrap a.item-top:hover{
    background-color: #000;
}
.menu > li .item-wrap a.item-bottom:hover{
    background-color: #778691;
}
.menu > li .item-wrap a span{
    display: block;
    transform: skewX(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
.menu > li .item-wrap a.item-top span{
    top: 0; left: 10px;    
}
.menu > li .item-wrap a.item-bottom span{
    bottom: 0; right: 10px;    
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <div class="item-wrap"> 
            <a href="#" class="item-top"><span>item1</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-wrap"> 
            <a href="#" class="item-bottom"><span>item2</span></a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-wrap"> 
            <a href="#" class="item-top"><span>item3</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-wrap"> 
            <a href="#" class="item-bottom"><span>item4</span></a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-wrap"> 
            <a href="#" class="item-top"><span>item5</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-wrap"> 
            <a href="#" class="item-bottom"><span>item6</span></a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h7k4f0z0/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

Должно вам помочь:
[Геометрические фигуры на CSS](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/)

или это: [Треугольники через CSS](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/treugolniki-cherez-css)